# Проблемы с записью в бд 1с

Tags: windows, 1с

Всем привет.

Проблема с 1с, я, к сожалению, в 1с, вообще, дуб-дубом, а сделать нужно. 
Система 1с файловая, сервер вин-8, он же рабочая станция с пользователем(к сожалению).

В общем проблема такая, С некоторых пор начались проблемы с записью в базу 1с или тупо ошибка блокировки таблиц. ниже прикладываю скрины.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1. Допустим проблема с запись в БД может быть вылечена с помощью собственной утилиты в 1с (chdbfl.exe), а как быть с блокировкой таблиц?? что то востановление через эту стандартную утилиту не помогает хотя должно, как я вычитал с сети!!!
2. блокировка таблиц - Все менеджеры (3 шт) работают вроди как, каждый под своим пользователем как они говорят, тк эта проблема выражется в мнопольном доступе на сколько мне известно из манов в сети...
3. Со слов менеджеров это началось недавно. На сколько мне известно то это началось когда там ктото поиграл с конфигами винды 8-й (сервер), и как я понимаю с политиками тк. сейчас порубан доступ через тим вьвер, т.е. через тимВьвер можно управлять только 1с. я пересмотрел вероятные места но ничего такого не нашел, хотя может и не все конф. пересмотрел спорить не стану. Возможно из-за этих сетевых политик и проблемы с 1с начались.
4. Бывает записи просто теряются в БД, т.е. трансакция вроди прошла а записи НЕТ - возможно проблема с индексами в бд?

Так вот вопрос на сколько это серьезно и как лучше поступить, просто не хочу за зря ложить сервак и заниматься перенастройкой под себя (он же рабочая станция с пользователем, надеюсь в скоре будет только сервак).

Помоготе плиз.

Заранее благодарен за ответ!!!

PS. Немного о себе. Я не админ, я кодер  и даже не 1с, но приходится пока что взять ее на себя пока не решится вопрос с новым админом. кстати есть весьма серьезное основание предполагать это это дело рук "местных"... хотя может и какойто троян бушует, но антивируса не находят ...

Comment: Самое главное научить менеджеров работающих с Файловой базой корректно завершать сеанс. Не оставлять сеансов с открытыми карточками документов, и т.п.

Comment: santavital "корректно завершать сеанс" - спасибо учту. Нужно маны почитать, полагаю, если что, там можно как то настроить авто-проводки при завершении сеанса

Answer (score 0):

Конфликт блокировок - это значит, что эти пользователи пытаюсь заблокировать одни и те же данные. Попробуй посмотри логи обращений пользователей. Ещё глупый вариант: может с винтом что-то? На винте бэды может, вот он базу и потёр. Прогони викторией попробуй. В общем вот, пока тебе пища для размышлений :D