# Настройка политик и безопасности в Виндовс

Tags: windows, безопасность, администрирование, teamviewer

Всем привет. 
Я не админ и по этому сразу к делу...

Проблема в том что на компе с виндой были сделаны настройки, где не могу понять, т.к. в данный момент тим вьвер может управлять только 1с, если начать шариться по компу, то он тупо вешается, в начале я подумал был что это вирус, а если точнее то гидра тк поведение компа при удаленном доступе было весьма показательным, но когда добрался до него в живую, то оказалось все в порядке и комп работает достаточно хорошо.

В общем что нужно сделать что бы вернуть управление, какие толковые маны по политикам и реестру винды можете посоветовать для подробного изучения...

Заранее благодарен за ответ.

PS. У меня есть еще один пост касательно данных проблем вот [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/984928/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D1%81-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C%D1%8E-%D0%B2-%D0%B1%D0%B4-1%D1%81)

Answer (score 0):

С помощью внутрисистемного поисковика или команды «Выполнить» запускаем штатную утилиту mmc.exe. В меню «Файл» консоли выбираем «Добавить или удалить оснастку».
В колонке справа выбираем «Редактор объектов групповой политики», жмём посередине «Добавить».
Заходим в «Обзор».
И добавляем пользователей. Выбираем:
• либо «Не администраторы», если нужно, чтобы настройки применялись ко всем имеющимся в системе учётным записям типа «Стандартный пользователь»;
• либо конкретного пользователя.
Далее "ОК", - "Готово".
Жмём «Ок» в окошке добавления оснасток, затем в меню «Файл» выбираем «Сохранить как».
Задаём файлу консоли имя, указываем какой-нибудь удобный путь сохранения, скажем, на рабочем столе, и сохраняем.
мы создали оснастку редактора групповой политики для отдельного пользователя. Это, по сути, тот же редактор, что и gpedit.msc, но ограниченный наличием только единственной ветки «Конфигурация пользователя». В этой ветке и будем работать с параметрами групповой политики.
Сохранённый файл консоли нужно будет запускать каждый раз при необходимости изменить параметры групповой политики для отдельных учётных записей.
 Запрет запуска отдельных программ

Если кого-то нужно ограничить в работе с отдельными программами или играми, следуем по пути:
Административные шаблоны - Система
Выбираем параметр «Не запускать указанные приложения Windows».
Включаем его, жмём «Применить».
Появится список запрещённых приложений. Кликаем «Показать» и в графы появившегося окошка поочерёдно выписываем десктопные программы и игры, запуск которых будет заблокирован. Вписываем их полное имя с расширением.
Кроме этого можно осуществить множество настроек запрета доступа к панели управления, к дискам компьютера, ограничения размера профиля и т.д.

Comment: спасибо, буду проверять